# Calendar regardless of settings

Tags: ios, swift, date, if-statement, calendar

In the application, I use the days of the week to open the achievements.

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

   if dayInWeek == "Monday" {

    achiv = true
}
```

I use English, Russian and Ukrainian languages ​​in the application. The problem is that this condition is valid if the phone is in English language. *Help pass this method so that the conditions work regardless of the language on the device*.

Comment: Use date components. Then you can use the weekday ordinal

Comment: @Paulw11 
Can you give an example for at least one day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `weekday` property of `DateComponents`

```
let now = Date()

let today = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.weekday, from: now)

if today == 2 {
    print("It is Monday")
}
```

Note that I am using the Gregorian calendar explicitly rather than the current calendar as weekday values can vary in other calendars.

Comment: Thanks! Good answer)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the weekday using DateComponents:

```swift
let date = Date()
let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
if weekday == 1 {
    print("Sunday")
} else if weekday == 2 {
    print("Monday")
}
```

Note: String checking `if weekday == "Monday"` is not safe, because different regions have different strings.